# How to re-set organisation for apigee learning edge tutorials?

Tags: apigee

I am going through this [apigee tutorial](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/learn-edge).
When the first time, this [script](https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/blob/master/learn-edge/simplest-proxy/deploy.sh) is invoked, it asks for the basic info regrading the user. By mistake, I gave the wrong organisation.

> Checking user configuration info ...
>
> Enter the password for user  on server
>   enterprise.apige
>   e.com.
>
> Password:
>   Verifying credentials on api.enterprise.apigee.com
>   ...
>   Organization  is invalid!
>   Please re-run the script
>   using the **right org**.

When I re-run the script, it is not asking me for the organisation. How can i set the organisation to the correct name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a  `userconf.sh` file in `trunk\setup`.

Scroll to the top of the file, you will see something like this-

```
# there are 2 main cases to handle:
# (a) the user's $HOME/.learn-edge.rc file exists,
# in which case we just dot it in; or
# (b) it doesn't exist, in which case we prompt
# for the values and write out to the config file.
```

Apigee writes all your basic info content in `$HOME/.learn-edge.rc`. Just modify this-

```
export org="youraccount-eval"
```

to the correct value and it will work.